# Having trouble with the borrow checker

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

Please help me understand what I'm doing wrong, I'm a new coder and also new to rust. I'm messing around with the code to figure things out and I keep running into issues trying to get this to work.

```
// Silence some warnings so they don't distract from the exercise.
// #![allow(unused_variables)]

// use standard library (allows me to get user input)
use std::io;

const MISSILE_PARAM: (i32, i32) = (8, 2);

// Using different variables
fn fire_in_the_hole(){
    let (mut missiles, ready) = MISSILE_PARAM;
    let mut command_str = String::new();
    let mut command;
    let mut new_missiles: i32 = 0;
    // Function to fire the torpedos
    let mut red_button = |missiles|{
        new_missiles = missiles;
        println!("Firing {} of my {} missiles...", ready, missiles);
        new_missiles = missiles - ready;
        println!("{} missiles left", missiles);
        println!("Fire again? [Y/N]");
        missiles
    };
    // Getting input from the 'General'
    let mut get_general_command = ||{
        io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut command_str)
        .expect("That's not a real command, General!");
    };
    println!("FIRE IN THE HOLE!!!");
    red_button(missiles);
    command = &mut command_str.trim();
    get_general_command();
    //Loop to ask if 'General' wants to keep fireing
    while missiles >= 2 {
        if (command as &str) == "Y" || (command as &str) == "y" {
            red_button(missiles);
        }
        else if (command as &str) == "N" || (command as &str) == "n" {
            println!(" Gotcha, General. We've got {} missiles left for next time.", missiles);
            break;
        }
        else {
        println!("That's not a real command, General! Please try again.");
        get_general_command();
        }
    }
    println!("All out of ammo, General.");
}
// Calculate the area
fn area_of(x: i32, y: i32) -> i32 {
    x*y
}
// Calculate the volume
fn volume_of(a: i32, b: i32, c: i32) -> i32 {
    a*b*c
}
fn main() {
    let width = 4;
    let height = 7;
    let depth = 10;
    let area = area_of(width, height);
    println!("Area is {}", area);

    let volume = volume_of(width, height, depth);
    println!("Volume is {}", volume);
}
```

I'm trying to get it to update the number of missiles after each fire but I'm getting errors about borrowing 'missiles'. Also having issues with the getting the command from the user.

Comment: It's best practice to include the error message in your question. Please edit your question and add it.

Comment: Sorry; makes sense.
This is what the linter mentioned:

line 32 - 
"cannot borrow 'command_str' as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable immutable borrow occurs here.
temporary value dropped while borrowed creates a temporary value which is freed while still in use."

I was also getting an error about borrowing 'missiles' to use in the red_button closure but when I put 'missiles' as a parameter it went away. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I specifically said to edit it into your question. Copy the error from the compiler output and paste it into a code block in your question.

Answer (score 2):

There's a few problems here.  I will go over them one at a time.

---

The first problem you're running into is that the closure you assign to `get_general_command` mutably borrows `command_str`.  To make this work, the compiler will generate a closure value and store the mutable borrow in it.  This means that `command_str` is mutably borrowed for as long as `get_general_command` exists, which means it cannot be used later -- not until you drop `get_general_command`.

You can fix this by changing this closure to not capture `command_str`, but rather to receive it as an argument.  (Note that you have to specify the type of the argument; if you don't, Rust infers the lifetime of the borrow incorrectly, creating the same problem you're trying to solve.)

```
let get_general_command = |buffer: &mut String|{
    io::stdin()
    .read_line(buffer)
    .expect("That's not a real command, General!");
};
```

Then you change your invocations to `get_general_command(&mut command_str)`.

These changes alter the duration of the mutable borrow of `command_str` to be just as long as the invocation of the closure.

Note that because the closure no longer captures anything, you could also convert it to a function outside of `fire_in_the_hole()`:

```
fn get_general_command(buffer: &mut String) {
    io::stdin()
    .read_line(buffer)
    .expect("That's not a real command, General!");
}
```

---

The second problem is this line:

```
command = &mut command_str.trim();
```

First, you're taking a mutable reference to a `&str` which doesn't really make a lot of sense.  The `&mut` here isn't really doing anything.

But the actual problem is that `trim()` returns a subslice of the input string, which means `command` is immutably borrowing from `command_str`.  Then, *on the very next line* you attempt to alter `command_str`.  This is not allowed, and I don't think it's actually what you're intending to do anyway.

Remove this line, and remove the corresponding `let mut command` declaration.  Then, add this as the first line of your `while` loop:

```
let command = command_str.trim();
```

This moves the trim (and borrow) to where you actually need it: right before you check what `command` is equal to.

---

With these changes, [the code compiles](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b5714266c22a5b6111577871864ee1a3).

---

Other notes:

- The cast `(command as &str)` is redundant.  `command` already is a `&str`, and casting in Rust is both very strict and rarely required.  If you aren't using `as` to convert between numeric types, using it to cast to `fn` types, or using it in/near `unsafe` code dealing with pointers, you almost certainly don't need it.
- `new_missles` is never read from after being assigned, and `missiles` is never assigned to after declaration and therefore doesn't need to be declared `mut`.  I assume this is because you aren't yet done writing the code, but I thought I'd point it out.

Comment: This has been so helpful, thank you very much. I'm still reading and re-reading your comment to try to grasp the concepts. 

My issue now is with the 'missiles' part, and it's just as you mentioned in your 2nd note. The only reason I tried using 'new_missiles' is because I kept getting borrow errors when trying to update 'missiles'. I'm having trouble understanding why I can't update the number of missiles in the 'red_button' closure (that's why I had 'missiles' and 'red_button' set to mutable). How can I update the number of 'missiles' and just get rid of the 'new_missiles' altogether?

Comment: @jdoh Probably the same as the issue with `command_str` -- because the closure mutates `missiles`, the closure mutably borrows it and this locks out all other access to `missiles`.